# Test variable against array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

Im thinking I should be using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) but for some reason it is giving me inaccurate information.  I looked through the [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) but it looks like that is only helpful if I have a key and value in my array which I dont.  In a nutshell Im running a condition to get the current EST time and day and determine if it is "during hours" or "after hours".

So it is 19:00 on Tuesday, this should say "After Hours" but it is echoing "During Hours", am I missing something?

Sample code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
$current_time = date('A'); //AM or PM
$current_day = date('l'); // Sunday - Saturday
$current_hour = date('H'); // 08 / 24hr Time Format

$closed_days = array('Saturday','Sunday');

$closed_hours = array('17','18','19','20','21','22','23','00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08');
?>
<?php
echo $current_time . '<br />';
echo $current_day . '<br />';
echo $current_hour . '<br />';
//Operating Hours
if(!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) || !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)) {
    echo 'During Hours';
} else { 
    echo 'After Hours';
} ?>
```

Is returning:

```
PM
Tuesday
19
During Hours
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
if(!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) || !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)) {
```

to

```
if(!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) && !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)) {
```

The || equates to "or" so the condition was returning true say it was an off day but during your normal hours

Using && equates to "and" which requires both conditional statements to be true to execute the code block

Comment: Makes sense, so would this hold true on if it was a day we were open but after hours?  I pretty much want to run some code if it is Monday - Fri between 9 Am and 5 PM else then do something else.  Im trying to wrap my brain around the "OR", "AND" logic.  Even though Im sure I am wrong my brain is telling me OR.  Like if current day does not equal Sat or Sun "OR" current hour is not in closed hours array.

Comment: Yes, since both conditions must be met. The logic of the updated condition reads "If current_day is not in the closed_days array AND the current_hour is not in the closed_hours array then display After Hours"

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is as simple as changing your if statement from:

```
!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) || !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)
```

To:

```
!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) && !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)
```

By using OR, you are saying only 1 condition has to be true

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if(!in_array($current_day, $closed_days) || !in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)) {
  echo 'During Hours';
} else { 
     echo 'After Hours';
}
```

to

```
if(in_array($current_day, $closed_days) || in_array($current_hour, $closed_hours)){
  echo 'After Hours';
}
else{
   echo 'During Hours';
}
```